# dropdown submenu over div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble with the display for small screens, particularly the drop down sub menu, when the drop down is clicked it affects the display and it won't align right, how do I display it on top of the div with proper alignment, it seems to be fine on bigger / wider screens,

please see below sample css and html code, i'm using bootstrap 4:

thank you in advance

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col--1 container-border navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark text-center">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html"><span class="oi oi-home" title="home" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col--3 container-border navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="myNavbar">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="z-index: 1;">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="z-index: 2;">
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Menu</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
              <hr>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Drop 2</a></li>
              <hr>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Drop 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <hr>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
              <hr>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Drop 2</a></li>
              <hr>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Drop 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <hr>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
              <hr>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Drop 2</a></li>
              <hr>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Drop 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col container-border navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark btn-group ml-auto container-border">
    <form name="frm1" class="form-inline btn-group-sm" action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="input-group ml-auto">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-light" type="submit">
         <span class="oi oi-magnifying-glass" title="icon magnify" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col--1 container-border navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">0</span><span class="oi oi-cart" title="cart" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

i wish it could behave like the big screen, please

Comment: If you want the item not to affect other elements, then you need to position it absolutely

Comment: you want the drop to be aligned next to sub menu?

Comment: i just want it to behave just like larger screens, kindly try small screen to see the difference. thanks

Answer (score 0):

after researching hours and hours, this one did it, 
ul and li position

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/hover-dropdown-list-is-pushing-other-content-down-the-page

i'm planning to changing the behaviour of the drop down though to use onclick and change contents instead, it seems that it isn't positioning on the right because it doesn't have space anymore.